# Experiencing navbar flicker with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm experiencing a flicker in my navbar before a function is evaluated to either true or false.

The function that needs to evaluate is the following:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    isAuthenticated () {
      return this.$store.state.user.authenticated
    }
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      unauthenticated: [
        {
          title: 'Link1',
          url: '/link1'
        },
        {
          title: 'Link2',
          url: '/link2'
        },
        {
          title: 'Link3',
          url: '/link3'
        }
      ],
      authenticated: [
        {
          title: 'otherLink1',
          url: '/otherlink1'
        },
        {
          title: 'otherLink2',
          url: '/otherlink2'
        },
        {
          title: 'otherLink3',
          url: '/otherlink3'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And the navbar has the following:

```
<template v-if="isAuthenticated()">
  <b-nav is-nav-bar>
    <b-nav-item v-for="nav in authenticated" :key="nav.title" :href="nav.url">{{nav.title}}</b-nav-item>
  </b-nav>
</template>
<template v-else>
  <b-nav is-nav-bar>
    <b-nav-item v-for="nav in unauthenticated" :key="nav.title" :href="nav.url">{{nav.title}}</b-nav-item>
  </b-nav>
</template>
```

However, when I click through the navigation, the unauthenticated links appear for a second and then the authenticated links appear as if the `isAuthenticated()` function hasn't evaluated yet. What can I do to remove this flicker?

My store file (user.js) file looks like this:

```
export const state = () => ({
  headers: {},
  profile: {}
})

export const mutations = {
  updateHeaders (state, headers) {
    state.headers.access_token = headers['access-token']
    state.headers.token_type = headers['token-type']
    state.headers.client = headers['client']
    state.headers.expiry = headers['expiry']
    state.headers.uid = headers['uid']
    if (state.headers.expiry == null) {
      state.authenticated = false
    } else {
      let timeToExpiry = new Date(state.headers.expiry * 1000)
      let now = new Date()
      state.authenticated = now < timeToExpiry
    }
  },
  signout (state) {
    state.headers = {}
    state.profile = {}
  }
}
```

The login/logout methods occur via API calls to a Rails app. The Devise gem handles the rest.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I am using Nuxt.js for the layouts/pages/components so I believe that links submit with a `this.$router.push(url)` under the hood.

The `b-nav` tags are coming from [Bootstrap Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/)

Comment: How are you setting the value of`user.authenticated` in your store is it by an ajax request?

Comment: I've updated my question :) the requests are occurring via calls like `this.$axios.delete('/auth/sign_out')` and then `this.$store.commit('user/signout')`

Comment: Have you tried setting the default value of `authenticated` in the store same way you do for `headers` and `profile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using bootstrap-vue there are two ways to add links to the navbar. One is to bind to `:href` attribute, which creates a regular html anchor. The other is to use `:to` attribute, which creates a link that interacts with vue-router.

```
<b-navbar-nav v-if="isAuthenticated()">
    <b-nav-item v-for="nav in authenticated" :key="nav.title" :to="nav.url">{{nav.title}}</b-nav-item>
</b-navbar-nav>
<b-navbar-nav v-if="!isAuthenticated()">
    <b-nav-item v-for="nav in unauthenticated" :key="nav.title" :to="nav.url">{{nav.title}}</b-nav-item>
</b-navbar-nav>
```

No reason to use `<template>` tags here to encapsulate the . Also note that 'is-nav-bar' is deprecated. See [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/navbar) where they note the deprecation.

Answer (score 0):

What code executes when you click one of the links is not stated, I assume it's something like `this.$router.push(url)`. If this is the case, you've probably have included your navbar in the `<router-view>`, so when you switch current route, components inside `<router-view>` rerender, so the navbar flashes. Move them out of the `<router-view>` should fix this.

*edit*: so the OP is not using `vue-router` yet, in this case, either manually change the root component's data to make parts other than the navs change, or add `vue-router` and use `this.$router.push()` to navigate so parts outside `<router-view>` won't change or flash.

Anyway, we need the vue component to stay to let vue to rerender only part of the view, while simply navigating by `<a>` or something will destruct everything and reconstruct them again, hence the flashing.

Comment: I am using Nuxt so I believe that Nuxt runs `this.$router.push(url)` under the hood? I'm not entirely sure tbh. Maybe I should specify in the question that I'm using Nuxt

Comment: @DaniG2k put some code on clicking the links may help.

Comment: The links are there... `<b-nav-item v-for="nav in authenticated" :key="nav.title" :href="nav.url">{{nav.title}}</b-nav-item>` and the entries are something like `{title: 'otherLink1', url: '/otherlink1' }`
The `b-nav-item` element comes from Bootstrap Vue

Comment: @DaniG2k The `href` is probably assigned to the `<a>` generated by `b-nav-item` (you can inspect the page DOM to make sure). Check out the answer edit.

Comment: The links look like this: `<li class="nav-item"><a href="/staff" target="_self" aria-disabled="false" class="nav-link">Staff</a></li>`

I'm not sure what you mean by `manually change the root component's data to make parts other than the navs change` Can you explain with an example please? I will give that a shot

Comment: @DaniG2k this is going a bit too far and I feel a bit messed up looking at it, how about make a minimal, working example(jsfiddle or SO snippets) and post another question?